# How to reference a function in my script file from the markup

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

My app has a flash/status message that appears during various events (login/logout for example). How can I reference the `Flash()` function from the markup?

### Markup

```
<div id="flash">this is a flash message</div>
<script>
    Flash.success(); // doesn't work. undefined.
</script>
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

    Flash = new Flash();

    function Flash() {
        this.success = function() {
            $('#flash').html('Success!');
        }
    }

});
```

How do I call the function from the markup?

Comment: Why did you wrap the `Flash` declaration in a DOMready handler? Just remove that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Flash` function is declared within the scope of another function, so it's not global, and therefore not accessible from your other script block.

The simplest fix is to change the declaration for the newly constructed object to explicitly add it to the global scope:

```
window.flash = new Flash();  // NB: lowercase for vars, uppercase for constructors
```

Longer term, a better fix (to avoid polluting the global namespace) is to put all of your own modules into their own namespace:

```
var MYNAMESPACE = MYNAMESPACE || {};
...

MYNAMESPACE.flash = new Flash();
```